# Method to convert Number(Currency) to Words

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

Is there any way in Pharo to convert a number to words.
For example: 1200 = one thousand two hundred only.

its not that hard to implement, but just curious to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Integer>>asWords` will do this.

`1200 asWords` returns `'one thousand, two hundred'`.

I found it by searching for "thousand" using Pharo's Finder tool.